# JQGrid Dropdown control, button click in same row

Tags: jqgrid

I have **JQGrid**, having dropdown control and button control in same row.
I have used `$("#grid).jqgrid('editRow', 0, true)` to show dropdown control. The cell besides dropdown is having button control, on which click i need to open popup box.
But, when I do editrow , it gives me `"tag of input type='button'"` written in my cell instead button control.

What should I do? Please guide.

Comment: You should provide the demo which demonstrates the problem or at least post the code which shows what you do exactly.

Comment: Thanks Oleg. I am sorry, i could not post demo as my code is dynamic and very lengthy and i don't have permission to copy code. Any ways, i found another way. I use doubleclickrow event and got cell from which i want to open pop up , and call function for open popup from there. So, instead button i use textbox and open popup from there.